# Running multiple dev projects in docker containers with nginx-proxy

Tags: nginx, docker

As I understand a `docker-compose` file, using the `docker-compose up` command, loads the images and starts the containers. Conversely using a `Dockerfile` file with the `docker build` command creates the image only. I think I am missing something here as things aren't working as I'd like.

Following the [bitnami/wordpress](https://hub.docker.com/r/bitnami/wordpress/) instructions I got an install running fine using `docker-compose up d`. Can then access via localhost:81

```
version: '2'
services:
  mariadb:
    image: bitnami/mariadb:latest
    volumes:
      - /path/to/mariadb-persistence:/bitnami/mariadb
  wordpress:
    image: bitnami/wordpress:latest
    depends_on:
      - mariadb
    ports:
      - '81:80'
      - '443:443'
    volumes:
      - ./wordpress-persistence:/bitnami/wordpress
      - ./apache-persistence:/bitnami/apache
      - ./php-persistence:/bitnami/php
```

Because I want to be able to access this as domain.com.dev, I looked at implementing [nginx-proxy](https://github.com/jwilder/nginx-proxy). Following the instructions there, and with some inspiration from [Docker nginx-proxy : proxy between containers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40293757/68763), I came up with the following:

```
version: '2'
services:
  nginx-proxy:
    image: jwilder/nginx-proxy
    container_name: nginx-proxy
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "88:80"
    volumes:
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro"

  mariadb:
    image: bitnami/mariadb:latest
    volumes:
      - //c/websites/domain_com/mariadb-persistence:/bitnami/mariadb
  domain.com.dev:
    image: bitnami/wordpress:latest
    depends_on:
      - mariadb
    ports:
      - '81:80'
    environment:
      - VIRTUAL_HOST=domain.com.dev
    volumes:
      - //c/websites/domain_com/wordpress-persistence:/bitnami/wordpress
      - //c/websites/domain_com/apache-persistence:/bitnami/apache
      - //c/websites/domain_com/php-persistence:/bitnami/php
```

Running `docker-compose up -d` with this appears to complete without error. However when I access domain.com.dev in a browser, I get a default Index of / page, which suggests I somehow got partway there but not all the way. Looking at the local folders, they get created but it seems like the `wordpress-persistence` does not get populated, which could explain the default view in the browser.

Any thoughts on why this isn't coming up as expected? Something obvious I missed?

Answer (score 0):

1) For the first approach, you need "to finish" the configuration.
If you don't have a running webserver (nginx, apache, etc.) (on port 80) - just change the port from `81` to `80`:

```
ports:
      - '80:80'
      - '443:443'
```

and add the record "`127.0.0.1  domain.com.dev`" to your `hosts` file (`/etc/host`s in linux).

*P.S. you may change port from `88` to `80` at the second approach - it will work without changing `hosts` file*

If you have a running wevserver on port 80 - then it is needed to you proxy directives at virtualhost config file. Here is an example:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    server_name _;

    include expires.conf;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header Host              $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP         $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For   $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_pass http://172.17.0.1:81;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
    }
}
```

2) The second approach is usually used with `dnsmasq` configuration.
Use [this](http://jasonwilder.com/blog/2014/03/25/automated-nginx-reverse-proxy-for-docker/) and [this](https://coderwall.com/p/qknu2g/local-docker-development-with-virtual-hosts) links to get more detailed information and examples of configuration.